# Error with declaring global dynamic array

Tags: c++, header, include, global-variables

I have the program setup like this.

myFiles.h

```
extern string * info = new string[5];
extern string filename;

void functionA(string filename, string *&info);
```

functionA.cpp

```
void functionA(string filename, string *&info)
{
    ... some code here ...
}
```

functionB.cpp

```
void functionB(string *&info)
{
    ... some code here ...
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    string * info = new string[5];
    string inputFilename;

    cout << "Enter your filename: ";
    cin >> inputFilename;
    functionA(inputFilename, info);
    functionB(info);
 }
```

When I try to compile the cpp files, I get

```
myFiles.h: warning: 'info' initialized and declared 'extern' extern string * info = new string[5];
multiple definition of 'info'
first defined here
```

*I am trying to make info array as the global variable in order to let my other function use it in the future. The data from functionA.cpp will store inside this info array.*

I don't understand the error. I declared the info in myFiles.h first isn't it? Then I have to declare this variable in my main.

Note: Assume the #include headers are all correct, and no vector is allow.

Comment: You can drop the two global variables in `myFiles.h`; your program never uses them anyhow. The variables defined in `main` are local variables, distinct from and unrelated to those global variables, despite having the same name.

Comment: Just did what you told me, it compiles now. But what if I have a functionB() that need to access this 'info' array? What is the right way to pass this data to functionB()?

Comment: The same way you pass it to `functionA`, I would imagine.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confuse here. For global variables, I just have to declare it in the main.cpp without declaring in .h with extern?

Comment: In the code shown, you don't need to declare any global variables. You are already not doing so in `main.cpp`, and you can drop `extern` declarations in the header. I suppose I don't understand the question.

Comment: My bad if you are unclear Igor (I am new to programming in general and tried my best to explain). I have modified my post with another functionB(). Will the above still work? Since you mentioned that there is no need to declare a global variable, I believe that 'info' and 'inputFilename' are actually local variable inside main.cpp? If 'info' data is changed in functionB(), will it affect the original 'info' in main.cpp?

Comment: Yes, you can drop the two `extern` lines in `myFiles.h`, and your program should compile. Yes, changes made to `info` in `functionB` would be visible in `main`, in the same way that changes made in `functionA` were (somehow, you didn't have any doubts about `functionA`; in what way do you feel `functionB` is different?)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! I was making sure that my understanding is correct which is why I introduced functionB and asking the question. What is the right way to "copy" this info data over to functionB where whatever is done to this info inside functionB, it will not affect the one in main.cpp? The info data is a dynamic array.